# Read a file created by root user on unix system

Tags: security, unix, file-permissions, hacking

I have a file created by root user on unix system and the file is assigned to a particular group.All I want to do is read that file by logging in as user which is not root and not a part that particular group and neither have sudo access.Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Be root, or have sudo access to commands which allow that access.

Comment: I suppose if you had physical access to the machine you could also boot the machine in single user mode, from a rescue disk, or take out the hard drive and mount it in another machine where you have root.

Comment: I can neither be root nor have access to sudo or to change groups

Comment: You'll either need physical access, or know much more about the machine, and the software installed to be able to exploit it.